# Dynamic network properties Android

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi

One of the methods to control network preference - setNetworkPreference() has been deprecated in Api 21. Official documentation suggests to use dynamic network properties instead, but there is no further info how to implement it. Can anyone explain what it is and will it work with previous Api? In one part of my app I just want to use SoftAP WiFi instead of mobile data.